# Calculating the singular configuration of a 3 revolute joint manipulator

Tags: inverse-kinematics, manipulator, jacobian, singularity

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me calculate the singular configuration of this simple manipulator[image: 3 link manipulator]

I am confused since J is a 2x3 matrix and I cannot simply calculate the derivative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure J is 2x3? it seems 3x3 to me

Comment: The third line refers to the angular velocity. I am looking for the linear velocity singularities (the first two lines, generally 2xn ).  I was thinking maybe det (JJ^T)=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $J$ is not square, solve $$|J^TJ| = 0$$ for $\theta_i$.

Answer (score 2):

Singular configurations are configurations at which the Jacobian is rank-deficient. In this case $J$ is a square matrix, you can find conditions for singularity by solving $\det(J) = 0$.

The last row of $J$ being all ones means that no matter the configuration, you can always generate some angular velocity. This actually implies that the conditions you get from solving $\det(J) = 0$ will be the conditions for linear velocity singularities.